# Filter and visualize in DataSlider only the dates when images available

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a code which is calculating NDVI for Sentinel data and creating DateSlider for this image collection for selected study area. Is there a way to filter and visualize in DataSlider only the dates when Sentinel images available?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/910fdca59ff1a98c9b27cd997d110401

Comment: I think you're out of luck. I don't see anything in the ui.DateSlider API that would allow for disabling specific dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateSlider does indeed not have that functionality. Maybe a `ui.Select' suites your needs? That will only contain of the dates actually available:

```
var allDates = ee.List(sentinel_dataset.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
var allDatesFormatted = allDates.map(function(date){
        return ee.Date(date).format('YYYY-MM-dd')
    }).distinct();


// UI widgets needs client-side data. evaluate()
// to get client-side values
allDatesFormatted.evaluate(renderSlider) 

function renderSlider(dates) {
  var selector = ui.Select({
                  items: dates, 
                  placeholder: 'Select a Date', 
                  value: dates[0], 
                  onChange: renderDateRange,
  });
  Map.add(selector);
}

function renderDateRange(date) {
  var image = collection
    .filterDate(ee.Date(date), ee.Date(date).advance(1, 'day'))
    .median()

  var vis = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'FCD163', '66A000', '207401',
    '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011301'
  ]}  
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(image, vis, 'NDVI')
  Map.layers().reset([layer])
}
```

[Link to this code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/534b811276a18dfaf4dad10c99340c94)

On the other hand, you might want to used the nice visual slide functionality, but always want to return an image. You could set the dateslider range at one day, and force the output to always add the image with the date closest to the user-defined date.

```
var collection = sentinel_dataset.map(function(image) {
  return image.select().addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])).rename('NDVI')
  // set dates to simple date 
     .set('system:time_start', 
          ee.Date(ee.Date(image.date()).format('YYYY-MM-dd')).millis())
});

var allDates = ee.List(sentinel_dataset.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
    // make a simple date, transform to millis to get similar dateNumbers per day
  return ee.Date(ee.Date(date).format('YYYY-MM-dd')).millis();
}).distinct();

// UI widgets needs client-side data. evaluate()
// to get client-side values of start and end period
ee.Dictionary({start: Start_period, end: End_period})
  .evaluate(renderSlider) 

function renderSlider(dates) {
  var slider = ui.DateSlider({
    start: dates.start.value, 
    end: dates.end.value, 
    period: 1, // Every 1 day
    onChange: renderDateRange
  })
  Map.add(slider)
}

function renderDateRange(dateRange) {

  // change date to the nearest available date
  var diff = allDatesSimple.map(function(dateNumber){
    return ee.Date(dateNumber).difference(dateRange.start(), 'hour').abs();
  });
  var hourDiff = diff.sort().getNumber(0).add(1);
         // add one hour to work around empty date ranges

  var image = collection
    .filterDate(dateRange.start().advance(hourDiff.multiply(-1), 'hour'), 
                dateRange.start().advance(hourDiff, 'hour'))
    .median()

  var vis = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'FCD163', '66A000', '207401',
    '056201', '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011301'
  ]}  
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(image, vis, 'NDVI')
  Map.layers().reset([layer])
}
```

[link to this code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4f81eddcf7e69b00d872b71f8f085cb6)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Is there a way to edit the position of ui.Select?

Comment: Check the style documentation